# Is it possible to convert a table row into string in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I am developing my first Android app. I have a table layout in my app, which will add rows dynamically. But, I want to convert the table rows into string. I tried "row.toString()" but I am not getting the expected result. Please find the following code snippet:

```
        View view = null;

        for(i = 0, j = tblayout.getChildCount(); i < j; i++)
        {
            view = tblayout.getChildAt(i);
            TableRow rw = (TableRow)tblayout.getChildAt(i);
            ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
            int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
            if(colorId == Color.parseColor("#E143ED23")) {
                num ++;
                //temCnt = view.toString();
                temCnt = rw.toString();
            }
       }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),temCnt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But it is not showing the actual table row data. It is showing some ids' or garbage value.

My requirement is:
I have 2 text boxes and 2 buttons. When the first button "Ok" is pressed the value inside the text boxes will be populated into the Table layout along with a checkbox. By default the row will be checked. But user can uncheck each items. After that, when the second button "Save All" is pressed, then it will search for all the table rows which are checked and it should insert the table rows into the my MS SQL table.

Is there any way for converting the table row into a string in Java? I really trapped on this. It would be very helpful if someone can help me on this.
Please help...

Comment: I think you have to get it cell by cell, looping through like `TextView cell = (TextView) rw.getChildAt(i);`

Comment: Why do you want to use toString(). you could use any method on TableRow to output exactly what you want.

Comment: Also, please add what you expect to get in the question, it will help to find a good solution.

Comment: @pmartin8: When a button is pressed it should write the checked table rows into a SQL table. Actually I am new to Android dev. So really confused how to do that.

Comment: Don't worry there are a lot of people out there to help you. But you need to be more precise in your question. What do you want to do exactly? Generate SQL statements from your java code? Automatically populate a SQL (what Database?) from your app? There are tons of ways...

Comment: @pmartin8 I have updated my question. Please have look & let me know if you want more info.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think you have two EditText, where the user can enter his/her desired text, and then the OK button is pressed which in turn will retrieve the text and insert it inside your table row? Is that right?

Comment: Hurray...!!! I fixed it. I did: TextView Name = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
                    TextView Num = (TextView) row.getChildAt(1);
                    TextView Cnt = (TextView) row.getChildAt(2); String Sname = Name.getText().toString();
                    String Snum = Num.getText().toString();
                    String Scnt = Cnt.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1):

toString() is a very basic method in Java, C# and other programming languages. Java's Object class has a basic implementation for it and you can override this method in any class that inherits from Object (that is, every class whatsoever :)). I don't know if those that developed the TableRow class of Android have overridden this method. It could be that what you're getting is some unreadable, meaningless representation of a TableRow object.

Let's say you have a TextView called txtName within the TableRow, followed by a second TextView called txtNumber. You can get what you want by doing the following:

```
...
ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
int colorId = viewColor.getColor();
if(colorId == Color.parseColor("#E143ED23")) {
    num ++;
    //temCnt = view.toString();
    TextView nameField = (TextView) rw.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    TextView numberField = (TextView) rw.findViewById(R.id.txtNumber);
    temCnt = nameField.getText().toString() + ": " + numberField.getText().toString();
}
...
```

Comment: My TextView are dynamic, I am creating textviews programmatically. So I cannot give my dynamic view id here findViewById(R.id.txtName)... So is there any other way?

Comment: Firstly, you can set an ID for a View you're creating dynamically with the setId() method. Just make sure the assigned IDs are unique. Secondly, if you have a reference to a View you're creating dynamically then you can ignore the findViewById() method - you already have a reference for that View.

Comment: Alternatively, you can iterate over the children of your TableRow and implement your own logic. For example, you can check if a certain child is a TextView with Java's instanceof keyword (v instanceof TextView), and if so, cast it to a TextView and proceed as above.